# How to require gtest in a conanfile.txt

Tags: conan

Where to put gtest in a conanfile.txt? In a conanfile.py it is suggested to use `test_requires("gtest/1.12.1@")`. However, there is no `[test_requires]` section in conanfile.txt.

I assume it is part of the library and should therefore be in the [requires] section. Or are there any reasons to put it under `[tool_requires]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `[test_requires]` section in the `conanfile.txt`, please [check this link](https://docs.conan.io/2/reference/conanfile_txt.html#test-requires)

In any case, a "test" requirement is intended for linking a library in the "host" context, like gtest, catch2, or similar. It shouldn't be defined as a `[tool_requires]`, if anything, it should be a regular `[requires]`. In the case of a `conanfile.txt`, as it is the end-consumer and there will be no further downstream consumers, there is no distinction in practice between a `requires` and a `test_requires`, as the main difference is that `test_requires` are private and not propagated down the graph.

Comment: Thanks for you answer drodri, I guess this is only available in conan 2.X? Because I am still forced to use 1.X, specifically 1.57 at the moment. In conan 1.X I get:
`ERROR: /home/user/...:
ConfigParser: Unrecognized field 'test_requires'`

Comment: The `test_requires` is Conan 2.0 feature. It's highly recommended that you update to latest version of Conan, due support and features. In case you really can not update to Conan 2.0, you should use gtest as build requirement instead `[build_requires]`.

Comment: Thanks @uilianries but aren't the package listed in the `[build_requires]` of a conanfile.txt only available during the build context? What if I also need to run the tests in the host context? Should I still use gtest in the `[build_requires]` and how do I force it then to be in the host context using only a conanfile.txt?

Comment: In a ``conanfile.txt`` in 1.X, a test-requires should be listed as a regular ``[requires]``, not as a ``[build_requires]``